# What are the center coördinates of the planes of a regular dodecahedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I'm programming a regular dodecahedron using [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Regular_dodecahedron) Wiki page. 
But I'm wondering, what are the center coördinates of the planes of a dodecahedron?

Comment: Do you have the vertex coordinates for the dodecahedron? If so, coordinates at the centre of a face can be found by averaging the coordinates of its vertices. If you don't have the vertex coordinates, they can be found [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Dodecahedron).

Comment: Yes, I do have those. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the *faces* instead of the planes. The faces are regular pentagons, so you can just take the average of the coordinates of the vertices.

E.g. in the picture below, the face which is turned towards us, and has one pink, two orange and two green vertices, has vertex coordinates $(\phi,0,1/\phi), (1,1,-1), (1,-1,-1), (0,1/\phi,-\phi), (0,-1/\phi,-\phi)$. The average is $(\frac{2+\phi}5, 0, \frac{1/\phi-2-2\phi}5)$ = $(\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10},0,\frac{-7-\sqrt5}{10})$. You can find similar coordinates for the other faces.

[image]

<sub>(source: [Wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Regular_dodecahedron))</sub>